# Difference between CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR & CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR variables?

Tags: build, cmake

as I understood, these variables are used in case project consist of sub directories e.g. every sub directory further have CMakeLists.txt files.

> CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR

refers to the path of source director under process ?
and

> CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR

refers to top most source directory ?
I am not sure about it.

Comment: Why don't you print them in different directories and see what they are? Like e.g. `message("CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are an awesome man (Y)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is where cmake was originally invoked, and `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is where cmake is currently working. For instance, if you use `add_subdirectory` command to include a dependency to your project, the dependency will have its own `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` but `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` will remain the same.

Expanding on Some programmer dude comment, imagine you have the following three CMakeFiles on different directories on your project

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

message("root dir CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
message("root dir CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_subdirectory(sub1)
add_subdirectory(sub2)
```

sub1/CMakeLists.txt

```
message("sub1 dir CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
message("sub1 dir CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

sub2/CMakeLists.txt

```
message("sub2 dir CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
message("sub2 dir CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

Running `cmake .` on the *root* directory gives me this output

```
root dir CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/henrique/cmake_tests
root dir CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/henrique/cmake_tests
sub1 dir CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/henrique/cmake_tests
sub1 dir CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/henrique/cmake_tests/sub1
sub2 dir CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/henrique/cmake_tests
sub2 dir CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/henrique/cmake_tests/sub2
```

Now if I run `cmake .` on the *sub1* directory I get the same value for both variables:

```
sub1 dir CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/henrique/cmake_tests/sub1
sub1 dir CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/henrique/cmake_tests/sub1
```